# Best way to dynamically compute/derive data from redux store based on component's local state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My fictional redux store looks like this:

```
// array of temperature measured every 4 hrs
{
  temp: [
    { t: 1547078400, c: 15 },
    { t: 1515528000, c: 16 },
    { t: 1515513600, c: 12 },
    { t: 1515499200, c: 10 },
    ...
    { t: 1546819200, c: 21 },
  ]
}
```

I have a widget which allows you to see the lowest temperature measured 'today', 'this week', 'this month' (The user can select the range by clicking buttons)

My reselect code would look something like this:

```
// Filter points if the time is within the specified range
const getHistory = (store, range) => 
   store.temp.filter(p => p.t < range.to && p.t > range.from);

// Get the points in the range and then find the min
const findMinTemp = (store, range) => createSelector(
  [getHistory],
  filteredPoints => filteredPoints.reduce(
    (minSoFar, point) =>  point.c < minSoFar.c ? point : minSoFar)
  )
)
```

**The Problem**
The above selector would work if the range was passed in as a prop.

```
// Dashboard.js
<MyComponent to={...} from={...} />

// MyComponent.js
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    min: findMinTemp(state, props)
})
```

What should I do if the range lives in my component's local state? I want to avoid saving the range in the redux store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can use memoization.

Reselect is basically a memoization helper for Redux. You can use the same technique inside your component (or anywhere basically). If you are not familiar with the concept [read here](https://codeburst.io/understanding-memoization-in-3-minutes-2e58daf33a19).

You can use any library you want, or even roll your own (these are very simple). React integration is simple: **You extract the computation logic** from your `render` method to another, **apply memoize to the extracted function** and call **that from `render`**.
There is a *React* + *memoize-one* example in the official docs [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization).

Comment: Memoize-one looks perfect. Will be using this!